# How to fix an error in Android Studio: xxx is not an enclosing class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a button that opens to a different activity.

I get an error that the `LoginActivity` class is not an enclosing class. My error is on this line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainPage.class);
```

Anyone can tell me how to fix it?

This is LoginLogic class

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(String res) {
    if (res.contains("id")){
        String regEx = "[^0-9]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(res);
        String getID = m.replaceAll("").trim();
        id = Integer.valueOf(getID).intValue();
        Toast.makeText(r.getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to CyChat!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainPage.class);
        intent.putExtra(MainPage.ID, id);
        r.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(r.getApplicationContext(), "Please check your username or password and try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

this is LoginActivity class

```
bt_Signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ISU_Email = enter_username.getText().toString().trim();
        password = enter_password.getText().toString().trim();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ISU_Email)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter your username(ISU Email)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if(!isValidISUEmail(ISU_Email)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "This Email is not a valid ISU Email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if(password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else {
            try {
                logic.loginUser(ISU_Email,password);
                //success login, move to main page
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            LoginActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `LoginActivity.this` within the `LoginLogic` class, only within the OnClickListener of the `LoginActivity` class. Unfortunately I don't know enough about the design of your classes to recommend a solution to this problem.

Comment: On which line is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try getApplicationContext instead of LoginActivity.this?